# posgresql - in clause to boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL have a table called "barn_animals" this table includes a column called `animal_type` of type `VARCHAR` , which includes animal-types such as `cat`, `dog`, `cow`, `chicken` ... 
Now I want to query only `dog` and `cat` into a `bool` column called `is_dog_not_cat` disregarding the other animal types. Therefore I wrote:

```
SELECT animal_type AS is_dog_not_cat
  FROM barn_animals
WHERE animal_type IN ('dog', 'cat');
```

This returns only cats and dogs as `VARCHAR` but is there a way to cast it to `bool` so it returns `True` for `dog` and `False` for `cat` into the `is_dog_not_cat` column instead of `dog` or `cat`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a boolean expression:

```
SELECT (animal_type = 'dog') AS is_dog_not_cat
FROM barn_animals
WHERE animal_type IN ('dog', 'cat');
```